# Udp server receive message from external client as if it is from server IP

Tags: c#, server, network-programming, udp, udpclient

I have a UDP Server and client which works on localhost when the server and client are both behind the same router.

When connecting from external IP - the IPEndPoint holds the server IP.

Server receiver:

```
private void Recv(IAsyncResult res)
{
    IPEndPoint clientEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);

    try
    {
        byte[] data = udpClient.EndReceive(res, ref clientEndPoint);
        udpClient.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(Recv), null);

        //Process codes
        RaiseDataReceived(new ReceivedDataArgs(clientEndPoint.Address, clientEndPoint.Port, data));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

When the server receives a message from external client, the clientEndPoint.Address holds the server's address, not the client address. Has anyone experienced this? I've tried multiple ways of receiving messages from clients without luck.

Comment: That's by design if you read Microsoft documentation on `Receive` and `ReceiveFrom`. Only the latter capture packet information, which includes the source IP address.

Comment: How is that a duplicate. I'm using async which isn't addressed in that question?

Comment: `BeginReceive` and `BeginReceiveFrom` mirror the same difference. More importantly, today you should use `ReceiveAsync` or `ReceiveFromAsync` due to the paradigm shift of async/await. Spend some time learning the history of async support of .NET, and you will understand the patterns.

Comment: @LexLi I'm currently at a point where I'm about to go nuts. Nothing I do changes the fact that when I get the clientEndPoint it's my public IP I get and not the client's public IP. Would you mind helping me out? I've tried BeginReceiveMessageFrom aswell as ReceiveAsync

Comment: I won't be able to help, as my experience on such (#SNMP Library) did not recall any similar cases. If you want more help from SO, provide a complete sample so that anyone can reproduce on their machines.